# how to cut the end of a string by some condition in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, os.path

I have searched possible ways but I am unable to mix those up yet. I have a string that is a path to the image.

```
myString= "D:/Train/16_partitions_annotated/partition1/images/AAAAA/073-1_00191.jpeg"
```

What I want to do is replace `images` with `IMAGES` and cut off the `073-1_00191.jpeg` part at the end. Thus, the new string string should be

```
newString = "D:/Train/16_partitions_annotated/partition1/IMAGES/AAAAA/"
```

And the chopped part (`073-1_00191.jpeg`) ***will be used separately*** as the name of processed image. The function `.replace()` doesn't work here as I need to provide `path` and `filename` as separate parameters.

The reason why I want to do is that I am accessing images through their paths and doing some stuff on them and when saving them I need to create another directory (in this case `IMAGES`) and the next directories after that (in this case `AAAAA`) should remain the same ( together with the name of corresponding image).

***Note that images may have different names and extensions***

*If something is not clear by my side please ask, I will try to clear up*

Comment: `os.path.split` or `os.path.dirname`/`os.path.basename` are what you want for splitting the final file's name from the path to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments, [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) is useful for manipulating paths represented as strings.

```
>>> import os

>>> myString= "D:/Train/16_partitions_annotated/partition1/images/AAAAA/073-1_00191.jpeg"

>>> dirname, basename = os.path.split(myString)

>>> dirname
'D:/Train/16_partitions_annotated/partition1/images/AAAAA'

>>> basename
'073-1_00191.jpeg'
```

At this point, how you want to handle capitalizing "images" is a function of your broader goal.  If you want to simply capitalize that specific word, `dirname.replace('images', 'IMAGES')` should suffice.  But you seem to be asking for a more generalized way to capitalize the *second to last directory in the absolute path*:

```
>>> def cap_penultimate(dirname):
...     h, t = os.path.split(dirname)
...     hh, ht = os.path.split(h)
...     return os.path.join(hh, ht.upper(), t)
... 

>>> cap_penultimate(dirname)
'D:/Train/16_partitions_annotated/partition1/IMAGES/AAAAA'
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple way :

```
myString= "D:/Train/16_partitions_annotated/partition1/images/AAAAA/073-1_00191.jpeg"

a = myString.rfind('/')

filename = myString[a+1:]

restofstring = myString[0:a]


alteredstring = restofstring.replace('images', 'IMAGES')
print(alteredstring)
```

output:

```
D:/Train/16_partitions_annotated/partition1/IMAGE/AAAAA
```

Answer (score -1):

It's game of slicing , Here you can try this :

```
myString= "D:/Train/16_partitions_annotated/partition1/images/AAAAA/073-1_00191.jpeg"

myString1=myString.split('/')


pre_data=myString1[:myString1.index('images')]

after_data=myString1[myString1.index('images'):]

after_data=['IMAGE'] + after_data[1:2]

print("/".join(pre_data+after_data))
```

output:

```
D:/Train/16_partitions_annotated/partition1/IMAGE/AAAAA
```